# Updating FireStore Recycler Adapter on Button Click

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore as my database and using Firestore Recycler Adapter to show the data inside my Firestore database.

My Recyclerview is displaying accurate data upon launching my app, but problem arise when I click the add button, which clears the data inside my recycler view.

This is **ItemAdapter.kt**

```
package com.fangs.inventory_management_system.adapter

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.fangs.inventory_management_system.R
import com.fangs.inventory_management_system.model.ItemModel
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.item_layout.view.*

class ItemAdapter (option : FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ItemModel>) : FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<ItemModel, ItemAdapter.ViewHolder>(option) {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {

        return ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false)
        )

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int, model: ItemModel) {

        holder.itemName.text = model.itemName
        holder.itemQuantity.text = model.itemQuantity.toString()

    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

        val itemName: TextView = itemView.tv_item_name
        val itemQuantity: TextView = itemView.tv_item_quantity
    }
}
```

this is my **MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.fangs.inventory_management_system.activity

import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.fangs.inventory_management_system.R
import com.fangs.inventory_management_system.adapter.ItemAdapter
import com.fangs.inventory_management_system.model.ItemModel
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
import com.google.firebase.auth.ktx.auth
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query
import com.google.firebase.firestore.ktx.firestore
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var adapter : ItemAdapter? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val userID = Firebase.auth.currentUser!!.uid

        updateRecyclerView()


        //get instance of Firestore db
        val db = Firebase.firestore
        val infoRef = db.collection("user").document(userID).collection("profile").document("info")
        infoRef.get()
            .addOnSuccessListener {document ->
                if(document != null){
                    //get the data as cast to hashmap
                    val data = document.data as HashMap<*, *>
                    //get the username field and set text for greet user as the same value inside firestore
                    val username = data["username"] as String
                    tv_greet_user.text = "Hello, $username"
                }
            }


        //add items in recycler view

        btn_add.setOnClickListener {

            addItem()
            updateRecyclerView()

        }

    }

    private fun updateRecyclerView() {

        //get root reference
        val root = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        val query = root!!.collection("item").orderBy("itemName", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
        val options = FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<ItemModel>().setQuery(query, ItemModel::class.java).build()

        rv_items.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        adapter = ItemAdapter(options)
        rv_items.adapter = adapter



    }

    private fun addItem() {

        //alert dialog
        val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        val layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.add_item_dialog, null)

        val itemName = layout.findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.et_item_name)
        val itemQuantity = layout.findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.et_item_quantity)

        dialog.setTitle("New Item Info")
        dialog.setCancelable(false)
        dialog.setView(layout)

        dialog.setPositiveButton("Add"){_,_ ->

            val newItem = ItemModel(itemName = itemName.text.toString(), itemQuantity = itemQuantity.text.toString().toInt())

            //open Firestore db
            val db = Firebase.firestore
            val collectionRef = db.collection("item")
            collectionRef.add(newItem)

        }

        dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel") {dialogInterface, _ ->
            dialogInterface.dismiss()
        }

        dialog.show()

    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        adapter!!.startListening()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        adapter!!.stopListening()
    }
}
```

This bug doesn't crash my app. But the data fail to be displayed upon adding a new item.
When I relaunch my app, it shows all the data.

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the `.add(newItem)` operation to see if something goes wrong?

Comment: Hi sir thank you for your reply. I tried adding listener to check if data are being saved without error as you said and nothing seems to be problematic. Upon reviewing my code, I found that updating the Recycler View inside the button was the problem. I removed it and data are now displayed accordingly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This block

```
btn_add.setOnClickListener {

            addItem()
            updateRecyclerView()

        }
```

This seems to be the root cause of the bug. I removed the **updateRecyclerView()** and it fixed the error.